# Swift 3 Parsing Json through UITableView with subtitle cell

Tags: json, uitableview, swift3, xcode8, subtitle

I'm new to Swift and I'm starting to pick it up faster and faster. But there's a few things that I can't seem to get right, even after hours and hours of deep google searching for something close to what I'm trying to get.

I have a json file like this that is called from a URL on the web:

```
{
  "closures": [
    {
        "organization_id": 1,
        "organization_type": "Library",
        "organization_name": "Adams Center Free Library",
        "organization_info": "Open Now"
    },
    {
        "organization_id": 2,
        "organization_type": "School",
        "organization_name": "Adirondack Central",
        "organization_info": "Closed Now"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to put this into a TableView Cell with a Subtitle option.

My goal is to have something like this going on as an example:

[image]

Like I said I'm new to Swift and with version 3 being new, all the tutorials I've come across are either too off for me to understand how I would go about implementing this into it or it's an Swift 2.0 example.

I wanna try and do this without anything like Alamofire where I have to deal with pods.

SwiftyJSON however, would be cool.

Sorry for such a weird request for help. I'm getting desperate though. I know how I would do something like this in PHP for web, but not Swift for iOS.

Thanks for your time and any help you provide!!!